# Как вывести пять случайных строк из одной категории?

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица с полями `id, name, hit`.
В ней 100 записей.
5 из них - `hit = 1`

Как правильно вывести в такой сортировке: В первой десятке всегда должны быть 5 товаров с `hit = 1`, перемешены случайно. Далее, остальные товары Random

Comment: `order by hit=1 desc, rand()`  Это если не надо из более чем 5 hit выбирать только 5

Answer (score 2):

```
select *
  from (
    select A.*,@nohit:=if(hit<>1,@nohit+1,0),@cnt:=if(@nohit=1,1,@cnt+1) num
      from (
            select *
              from table
             order by hit=1 desc, rand()
           ) A, (select @cnt:=0,@nohit:=0) B
  ) A
order by num<=5 desc, rand()
```

Здесь сначала все hit=1 ставятся в начале и все записи сортируются в случайном порядке. Далее в этом наборе hit=1 и hit<>1 нумеруются подряд, отдельно, начиная с 1. Т.е. записи hit=1 с номерами 1,2,3,... и точно так же hit<>1 1,2,3,... Этот набор мы сортируем еще раз, на этот раз в начале идут записи с номерами меньшими 5 (их как раз 10, по 5 хитовых и не хитовых), а дальше все остальные.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `om_table`
    WHERE `hit` = 1
    ORDER BY rand()
    LIMIT 5
UNION
SELECT * FROM `om_table`
    WHERE `hit` <> 1
    ORDER BY rand()
    LIMIT 5
```

Comment: А вы запросы проверяете перед тем как ответ написать ? на такое MySQL говорит _ERROR 1221 (HY000): Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY_

Comment: Не проверял, давайте свою версию MySQL и в ней проверю.

Comment: Это на любой версии MySQL будет и на любой другой RDBMS то же будет ошибка, потому что по стандартам SQL ORDER BY применяется _после_ того как отработает UNION, поэтому надо делать union подзапросов. НО SQL (по стандарту) не гарантирует что записи первой части union будут обязательно перед записями второй части, хотя MySQL текущих версий действительно ставит записи по порядку следования union'ов